# How to copy the value of the click through the anchor and add this value through the input and remove?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code does not work the way I want it to. It is to copy the value of the click through the anchor and add this value through the input and remove. Can you help me? The code is for an interaction feature in the field. I'm creating a form and I'm trying to add this feature. My idea is ...

**Explanation of idea and code with pseudo-algorithm**

```
if (click) { remove input }
input. removed { step 1 }
Step 1 :: Now add this <a> 1 anchor </a>

if ( click ) {   if (step1) is 'correct'! {    else (copy text value) .create input   }  createinput 'is'   }   'is'  =  input.add {  ( add text value ) }
       
now: remove the anchor ^ step2 ^ 
Step 2 :: Now add this <input></input>
end-script
```

***Translation 1***

1. Remove input and add the anchor.
2. Add anchor and if (click)... add value of text in (input).
3. To add the input create a new input and then remove the anchor.

***Translation 2***

```
  HTML(Values.txt) is '<a href="#">Presencial</a>'
  HTML(Values.txt) is'<a href="#">Online</a>'

  take.valueTXT ( Presencial, Online) = Text.content for Value.Input )

  'take.valueTXT' 'is' ( expression )  
     
   '(expression)' 'is'  'rule' 

   'rule' is $("#presencial,#online").text($('#inscricao').val(););
```

***Translation 3***

```
$(function()
{
    var find = $("#presencial, #online").text("");
    var add = $("#input").val("");
    var make = find to add; 
    
   $('<input>').addClass('inscricao u-full-width').attr({id: 'inscricao'});


});
```

***Translation 4***

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("#presencial,#online").innerText;
  var a = $("#inscricao").val();
  a = x;
```

***Translation 5***

```
$("#presencial,#online").text($("#inscricao").val();)
```

***Translation 6***

```
      $("#presencial,#online").click(function() {
       $("#presencial,#online").text( $("#inscricao").val(); )
       $("#presencial,#online").remove();
       $("input").add(); // add input
   });
```

***Translation 7***

```
document.getElementById("#presencial,#online").innerText;.$("#inscricao").val();
```

**Errors, Source-Code**

```
// script 1
$("#inscricao").one("click", function() {
    $('#inscricao').after('<div style="text-align:center"><a id="presencial" style="text-decoration:none;" href="#">Presencial</a><a id="online"  style="text-decoration:none;">Online</a></div>');
    jQuery('#inscricao').remove();
});
// script 2
      $("#presencial").click(function() { 
                    $("#presencial").val(function(c) { 
                        $('#presencial').after('<input class="inscricao u-full-width" id="colegios" type="text" autocomplete="off" required/>');

/* var take = document.querySelector('#presencial').innerHTML; var adicionar = document.querySelector("#presencial").value = take;  */

                        var c = $("#inscricao").text();
                        return c. 

                        jQuery('#presencial').remove();

                    }); 
                });
```

Reference

- https://jsfiddle.net/pedroguilherme/e0b8jrpk/42/
- https://jsfiddle.net/pedroguilherme/82Lbfac1/2/

**IDEA**

```
 var take = document.querySelector('#presencial').innerHTML; var adicionar = document.querySelector("#presencial").value = take;
```

### Test1

```js
$("#inscricao").one("click", function() {
  $('#inscricao').after('<div style="text-align:center"><a onclick="addInput(this.form);copyValue(this.form); removerHere(this.form);" id="presencial" style="text-decoration:none;" href="#">Presencial</a><a onclick="addInput(this.form);copyValue(this.form); removerHe(this.form);" id="online"  style="text-decoration:none;">Online</a></div>');
  jQuery('#inscricao, #label1').remove();
});

$("#unidades").one("click", function() {
  $('#unidades').after('<div style="text-align:center"><a onclick="addInput(this.form);copyValue(this.form); removerHere(this.form);" style="text-decoration:none;">Recife</a><a onclick="addInput(this.form);copyValue(this.form); removerHere(this.form);" href="#" id="jabatao" style="text-decoration:none;">Jabatão</a></div>');
  jQuery('#unidades,#label2').remove();
});

$("#colegios").one("click", function() {
  $('#colegios').after('<div style="text-align:center"><a onclick="addInput(this.form);copyValue(this.form); removerHere(this.form);" href="#" id="cdfmaster" style="text-decoration:none;">CDF Master</a><a onclick="addInput(this.form);copyValue(this.form); removerHere(this.form);" href="#" id="meninojesus" style="text-decoration:none;">Menino Jesus</a><a  onclick="addInput(this.form);copyValue(this.form); removerHe(this.form);" href="#" id="ethos" style="text-decoration:none;">Ethos</a></div>')
  ;
  jQuery('#colegios,#label3').remove();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

input,
label {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline;
}

label {
  float: left;
}

a {
  padding: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bolder;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="label1">Inscrição</label>
<input id="inscricao">

<label id="label2">Unidades</label>
<input id="unidades">

<label id="label3">Colégios</label>
<input id="colegios">
```

### Test2!

Source-code work now! **enter code here;D**

**STEPS/ Translation 8!**

```
// $().ready(function(e){}
$("#inscricao").one("click", function() {
    $('#inscricao').after('<div style="text-align:center"><a id="presencial" style="text-decoration:none;">Presencial</a><a id="online"  style="text-decoration:none;">Online</a></div>');
    jQuery('#inscricao').remove();
});


$("#unidades").one("click", function() {
    $('#unidades').after('<div style="text-align:center"><a style="text-decoration:none;">Recife</a><a id="jabatao" style="text-decoration:none;">Jabatão</a></div>');
    jQuery('#unidades').remove();
});


$("#colegios").one("click", function() {
    $('#colegios').after('<div style="text-align:center"><a id="cdfmaster" style="text-decoration:none;">CDF Master</a><a id="meninojesus" style="text-decoration:none;">Menino Jesus</a><a  id="ethos" style="text-decoration:none;">Ethos</a></div>');
    jQuery('#colegios').remove();

});


$("#presencial, #online").click(function() {
  var text = $( this ).text();
  $( "input" ).val( text );  
});

$("#recife, #jabatao").click(function() {
  var text = $( this ).text();
  $( "input" ).val( text );
  <input class="nomecompleto u-full-width" id="nome" type="text" autocomplete="off" required>
});

$("#cdfmaster, #meninojesus, #ethos").click(function() {
  var text = $( this ).text();
  $( "input" ).val( text );

});
```

***Steps of Source-Code***

1. If(click) in input... this input: `<input class="inscricao u-full-width" id="nome" type="text" autocomplete="off" required>`
2. So... remove input and add anchor....! this anchor: `<a>Presencial</a>Online<a></a>`
3. If(click) in anchor "if (click) in anchor is each".... So... get value and add in input.`<input class="inscricao u-full-width" id="nome" type="text" autocomplete="off" required>`

**KnowHow**

1. I use   `$("#inscricao").one("click", function() { $('#inscricao').after('<div style="text-align:center"><a id="presencial" style="text-decoration:none;">Presencial</a><a id="online"  style="text-decoration:none;">Online</a></div>');jQuery('#inscricao').remove();});`

**Steps of 1**

1. `$("#inscricao").one("click", function() {`

Describe: Get input with id and if (click)... one and... replace inscricao with id inscricao....

**So example**

`$('#inscricao').after('<div style="text-align:center"><a id="presencial" style="text-decoration:none;">Presencial</a><a id="online"  style="text-decoration:none;">Online</a></div>');`

2. jQuery('#inscricao').remove();

**So example**

`$("#inscricao").one("click", function() { $('#inscricao').after('<div style="text-align:center"><a id="presencial" style="text-decoration:none;">Presencial</a><a id="online"  style="text-decoration:none;">Online</a></div>');jQuery('#inscricao').remove();});`

Describe: I add click in input that remove input and add anchor.

**Step Source-Code 2**

```
$("#presencial, #online").click(function() {
  var text = $( this ).text();
  $( "input" ).val( text );  
});
```

Describe: If click in anchor... So, add value text in input. 'Value text is value from here Presencial'... So, add value in input is 'Get value text in >Presencial< and add in input'

**Problem**

- How return in input if I remove in **Source-Code 1**?

***Solve!***

- Add after in anchor! But, How I add?

***Problem and Describe***

1. How I return in one input... if click one in anchor?
2. How Add two variables in one?

***Example 1 and 2***

```
$("#inscricao").one("click", function() {
    $('#inscricao').after('<div style="text-align:center"><a id="presencial" style="text-decoration:none;">Presencial</a><a id="online"  style="text-decoration:none;">Online</a></div>');
    jQuery('#inscricao').remove();
$("#presencial, #online").click(function() {
  var text = $( this ).text();
  $( "input" ).val( text );  
});
});
```

Describe: I trying this... But, no work **:/**

**Problem**

Describe: I trying one function with this... But, no work **:/** Why?

***Solve with the simple***

> Stop writing bad code! Stop being a kiddie script! Lol ... ^^

## How?

1. Read http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function
2. Read https://api.jquery.com/click/
3. Use concept val-function + click function

## How?

1. `$( "#multiple" ).val([ "Multiple2", "Multiple3" ]);`

Describe: You have used id and get value inside options in select. Sorry, I no understand... and Calm!

2. So... Add this inside value as value input!
3. With this... you no remove input and add anchor and add new input and remove anchor!

**How!?**

1. I'm not stupid, I do not understand code! ;D

**Step of Solve**

```
1. $("#multiple").val(["Multiple2","Multiple3"]);
2. Add values of id #Multiple2, #Multiple3 if click in input!
```

**Source-code**

```
// set id and add ip select
 $("#presencial,#online").click(function() {
       $("#presencial,#online").text( $("#inscricao").val(); )
     
      // if click in select add value in input
        $("input").add(); // add input
   });


// I tried like this

// If I click in select... So... add value of select in input 
$( "#Multiple2, #Multiple3" ).click(function() {
  var text = $( this ).text();
  $( "input" ).val( text );
  
});

// But, no work... I trying add $(this).prev('input').val("#Multiple2, #Multiple3").click;
```

Comment: Your first fiddle has a syntax error, check the JavaScript console.

Comment: Please use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) instead of jsfiddle.

Comment: **Add anchor and if (click)... add value of text in (input).** Add the value where?

Comment: How does text get into the input? You can't type into it, because first you have to click on it, and that removes it.

Comment: You're just saying the same thing you wrote in the question. I didn't understand it the first time, I still don't.

Comment: Where should it add the value of the text of the anchor? You can't add it to the input, because you removed the input.

Comment: `new_input.val($(this).text())`

Comment: You have `this.form`, but there's no form in your HTML. The `form` attribute only works on inputs, not anchors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replaceWith()` method to replace the anchor with an input. Use `$(this).text()` to get the value of the new input.

Use event delegation to write the event handler for the anchors, rather than putting `onclick` attributes in each of them. See [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

```js
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($("<input>", {
    value: $(this).text()
  }));
});

$("#inscricao").one("click", function() {
  $('#inscricao, #label1').replaceWith('<div style="text-align:center"><a id="presencial" style="text-decoration:none;" href="#">Presencial</a><a id="online"  style="text-decoration:none;">Online</a></div>');
});

$("#unidades").one("click", function() {
  $('#unidades,#label2').replaceWith('<div style="text-align:center"><a style="text-decoration:none;">Recife</a><a href="#" id="jabatao" style="text-decoration:none;">Jabatão</a></div>');
});

$("#colegios").one("click", function() {
  $('#colegios, #label3').replaceWith('<div style="text-align:center"><a href="#" id="cdfmaster" style="text-decoration:none;">CDF Master</a><a href="#" id="ethos" style="text-decoration:none;">Ethos</a></div>');
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

input,
label {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline;
}

label {
  float: left;
}

a {
  padding: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 20px;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bolder;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="label1">Inscrição</label>
<input id="inscricao">

<label id="label2">Unidades</label>
<input id="unidades">

<label id="label3">Colégios</label>
<input id="colegios">
```

Comment: I don't know jsPDF, I can't help you with that.

Comment: Use a class to specify the anchors that should have this special behavior, and change `"a"` to `"a.class"` where `class` is the class name you've chosen.